# How to Launch SPL Token on Solana Mainnet

Tags: spl-token, mainnet

As far as I knew the use created SPL token was added to the Solana production by adding to the token-list file under GitHub i.e https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list.
However, it's deprecated now.

Can someone help me to guide the new process for launching a new user-created SPL token to the Solana network?

Answer (score 2):

The current method is to use Metaplex Token Metadata in order to add token information on-chain.

You can learn more about it at https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/

Comment: I have already created the payer account , mint token and token account on CLI, now trying to move the mint token to production, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the metaplex JS SDK is the easiest tool to add your metadata.

Here's a [guide](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-create-a-fungible-spl-token-with-the-new-metaplex-token-standard/#build-a-mint-tool) to walk through it. Since you already have a token you might be able to skip a few steps.